# _gaq.push(['_trackEvent' is not triggered from jQuery after successful AJAX form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, google-analytics

I am trying to track contact submission events with Google Analytics' `_gaq.push(['_trackEvent'` to keep track of contacts conversion without any results.

The contact form is being displayed with a FancyBox dialog and submitted with AJAX. After successful submit, the form is replaced by a message, so for better usability I do a FancyBox window resize and make sure that the user sees the message by scrolling to the top (see extra code below).

The form is rendered with Drupal Form API and submitted with `drupal_json()`.

Basically, my code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#contacts a").fancybox();
    // after submit I need to resize the fancybox window
    $("#contact-mail-page").bind("submit", function() { 
        $.fancybox.resize();
    });

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    if ( settings.url === "/feedback" ) {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
        // rec event
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'action', 'contact', 'site feedback', '1']);
    }
});
```

Why is `_gaq.push(['_trackEvent'` not triggered from jQuery after successful AJAX form submit?

ANSWER
_gaq.push _trackEvent The _trackEvent API expects a number value for argument 3. The argument given (1) was a string.

Comment: when you `console.log(settings)` in the `ajaxComplete` callback, what do you have?

Comment: What is settings var?

Comment: its the third parameter passed into the function. perhaps its best that you learn what the code you're using actually does before asking us what's wrong.

Comment: You think settings.url is not /feedback? It is /feedback from console.log(settings) output

Comment: Based on that last comment, the `if` block inside `ajaxComplete` will be executed. Are you seeing any javascript errors that are happening inside that if? If you are not seeing any errors, then based on the code you have provided, the line in question will execute, and the problem might not be that the line is not called but that there is something else wrong.

Comment: The answer is string instead of integer: _gaq.push _trackEvent The _trackEvent API expects a number value for argument 3. The argument given (1) was a string.